# how to add subtitle and create progress bar in VLCKit?(swift)

Tags: swift, swiftui, progress-bar, vlc, subtitle

i want to add subtitle in my video player , i using VLCKit and when i add **addPlaybackSlave(subtitle_url, type: .subtitle, enforce: true)** thats do nothing and subtitle isn't displayed

this is part of my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileVLCKit

struct ContentView: View {

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "My Video", withExtension: "mp4")!


var body: some View {
    PlayerView(url: url)
        .onAppear {
            
        }
}
}

struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {


public var url: URL
let mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

let subtitle_url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "My subtitle", withExtension: "srt")

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {

    let controller = UIView()
    mediaPlayer.drawable = controller
    let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
    mediaPlayer.media = media
    mediaPlayer.addPlaybackSlave(subtitle_url, type: .subtitle, enforce: true)
    
    mediaPlayer.play()
    
    return controller
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
}
}
```

And someone know how can I create progress bar for VLCKit?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.